# any app for interview transcription available

Tags: lubuntu, appmenu

I am a new Lubuntu user and I need some help. For a project at university I need to transcribe interviews. Our professor has recommended us a software which is downloadable for Linux: http://www.exmaralda.org/downloads/ .. I downloaded the package, but I can't figure out how to install it (doesn't work with the install-tool GDebi).
Do you have any tips? Or is there any app for scientific transcribing which I could get directly from the Lubuntu Softwarecentre?

Looking forward to your answers.

P.S.: if there are some Ubuntu-apps for transcription, it would be preferable for me (as there is a SPSS-substitute for ubuntu there might as well be some transcription app which I simply haven't found so far in the software-centre)..

Answer (score 0):

You can also install from this PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install emerald
```